# How to see which javascript is getting executed in real time

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I'm working on a complex web app that has many javascript functions from various files dynamically generating content and actions on the page. I need to figure out which functions are being called so I can debug and fix issues, but I can't figure out how to watch which functions/scripts are getting executed in real time. I tried to use Firebug (firefox v.28), ie developer tools (ie 11), and chrome (v. 33.0.1…), but I don't see anywhere that is shows me the function that is being called.

There are 100 functions across many js files and jquery. I don't know the name of the function, so I can't just look that up and set break points.

Is this not possible? Or am I not doing the steps with the debugging tools correctly?

Comment: In debugging tools there is pause button which will pause whatever JavaScript will run after clicking on it and let you debug.

Comment: I believe if you put a `debugger` statement in your Javascript and have your console open, it will pause automatically at that point. Then you can step through the code.
That's how it works in Chrome, anyway. I have never used firebug

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Epsilon there's a [Break On Next](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel#Break_On_Next) button, which allows you to stop the script execution at the next executed statement and as derstrom8 said you can also place the `debugger` keyword within your code to stop at a specific line.

And there are many other ways how to debug your scripts, e.g. by breaking on exceptions or logging function calls.

You may want to read [how JavaScript debugging in Firebug works](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Debugging). The other devtools have similar functionalities.